# Software for auto-cropping and aligning digitalised archival documents

Tags: photography, archiving

I have just digitalised a huge archive of letters (more then 20.000 documents) and am now looking for some software that would help me auto-crop and align my photos. My collection consists of photographs of a mostly white letter paper on black surface. The photos now need to be cropped (about an inch around the border of the letter) and since some a slightly tilted, they need to be aligned as well. Since I have more than 60.000 photos, I was wondering if any software can do that for you automatically. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine using a command line tool, you can take a look at [**Deskew**](https://github.com/galfar/deskew).

It will deskew the images, and has a flag (`-g c`) for auto-cropping.

Before and afters:
[image]
[image]

Other options - with GUIs but also quite complicated - are:

1. **ScanKromsator**: http://www.djvu-soft.narod.ru/kromsator/eng.htm
2. **Scan Tailor**: https://scantailor.org/